# Is there a functional representation for strict evaluation?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghc, fold, strict

I want to implement the strict folding functions myself, from within Haskell: Is this possible? I've read that Lisp macros can be used to redefine the language to a massive extent, giving you the power to effectively break out of the functional paradigm whenever you need to and mould it into a personalised paradigm that gets the job done in the neatest way possible. I don't actually know lisp so that may be incorrect.

When you also take into account that in the untyped lambda calculus data types are encoded as functions, I begin to suspect that anything can be encoded as anything else (The brilliant book [GEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) discusses this in some detail). In that case, representing strict evaluation sounds like it should be easy.

So, how would you go about implementing the following from within haskell?

```
foldl'  = -- ???
foldl1' = -- ???
```

I suspect it has something to do with Monads and/or Continuation Passing.

Comment: LISP is *fundamentally different* from Haskell. Anyway, a LISP macro, while it has the ability to add *many* new forms, can hardly make a LISP inherently lazy (although HoFs/CPS can be used in many cases) or add continuation support -- excepting as the dialect already has the fundamental properties to do so. And I daresay there are no amount of macros that can make a standard LISP dialect like Haskell ;-) LISP is still LISP, the ability to make DSLs easily aside.

Comment: You could always just click the "source" links in [the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#g:3) to see how they are implemented in the standard library.

Comment: Note that a strict `foldr` would run against the spirit of that function, the ability to (begin to) produce results without evaluating the recursive call is a _very_ important point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can you implement `foldl'`? [Like this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#foldl%27)

Haskell provides the `seq` primitive for adding strictness, and "bang patterns" as well for convenience.

See also: [Haskell 2010 > Predefined Types and Classes # Strict Evaluation](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1260006.2)